# Unity uncaught translation error: illegalArgumentException

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 5.4.1p2 pro version

Enabled analytics and google play inapp purchase

Added the below unity ad network sdks
Charboost 6.4.1
Admob
Revmob
Vungle

In addition to these sdks, I also have the dependency sdks like
Googleplayservices

After integrating all these sdks, app is working fine in editor. But while taking build, I am getting the below error

> Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbn;

This error occurs at conversion to dex format phase

It seems there is a conflict of having same dependency in multiple places...

Anyone seen this before???

Comment: Did you see [this](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1176)?

Comment: Playservices-ads and play-services-ads-lite is there. ... thats the problem right ??

Comment: Whose dependency is ads lite ?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lite, then you need to disable play-services-ads.jar.

Please see the attached screenshot below to disable play-services-ads.jar

[image]

it will never compile if you have these 2 jars. Disable that jar and try taking build, it should go past dex conversion phase.